# Why does my custom type evaluate to boolean?

Tags: typescript

```
type IsFirstTrue<T extends unknown[]> =
  T extends [infer First,  ...infer Rest] 
  ? First extends true
    ? true
    : false
  : false

// let a: boolean
let a: IsIndexedTypeTrue<[boolean]>
```

I'm trying to create a type `IsFirstTrue` that checks whether the first element of an array type is of type `true`.

For the type `[boolean]` as input the resulting type should evaluate to `false` since its first type is not of type `true`, but it evaluates to `boolean` instead, which is odd since in the code the `boolean` type is not even stated, only `true` or `false`. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `boolean` is neither `true` nor `false` (it is a representation of a union of both):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gIwFzwxgFcEAfeAMygjRAG4AoeZl15genYD0B+BoA)

```ts
declare const b: true | false;
            //^? const b: boolean
```

I think you're probably looking for something like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgzgMQJYCc7ACooK4QDwZQQAewEAdgCZxQoQCGlA9uQDYhTbkDW5TA7uQDaAXQB8UALwAoKFEIkyVGkOA4IAGigA6XXUYt2nHn0GiRsuVAD8UNbktyAXFABm9VnAgBuadMoQAMas9HRQgSzoUPQu8MhomOp4QgBGTEysDOTivlZ5+QD0BQB61n4BwaHQEeRRKbGIqOhYuMn2EDmO+XlFpeVBIWE1UYEN8c1JQu6eHWK53YUlZf4DVeGRwFCUY02JrULoKEjkAOadC4t9K5VDG0Q7CS34QuTYALYpECjnF1a9yxVBtU7q4HhN9u0tK8Pl8fr8oP8-EUdLoIMBAtppEA)

```ts
type IsFirstTrue<T extends readonly unknown[]> =
  T extends [true, ...readonly unknown[]]
    ? true
    : false;

declare const a: IsFirstTrue<[boolean]>;
            //^? const a: false

declare const b: IsFirstTrue<[true]>;
            //^? const b: true

declare const c: IsFirstTrue<[false]>;
            //^? const c: false

declare const d: IsFirstTrue<[string]>;
            //^? const d: false

declare const e: IsFirstTrue<[number]>;
            //^? const e: false

declare const f: IsFirstTrue<[true, number]>;
            //^?  const f: true

// ...etc.
```

Comment: So since `boolean` is union it applied logic as in distributed conditional types? (I thought distributed conditional types applied to generic naked types which are unions, does `First` qualify as such?)

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74590098/why-does-my-custom-type-evaluate-to-boolean/74590190#comment131667478_74590190) My guess is yes, but I'm not sure how to extract that information out of the compiler for a _verifiable_ answer. Perhaps it's possible to get it out of an intermediate AST representation or using the compiler API? @jcalz might know something about that.

Comment: ok no big deal I was asking mainly out of curiosity, but if jcalz can add more info, will be even better.